# Dynamically populate version from version.sbt

Tags: sbt, logback

I'm trying to take the version from `version.sbt` and and populate it to `logback.xml`'s log appender's `applicationVersion` field.

**version.sbt**

`version in ThisBuild := "0.4.63"`

**logback.xml**

```xml
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">

    <appender name="ADP-MESSAGING" class="com.agoda.adp.messaging.logging.appenders.LogbackAppender">
        <applicationName>MyApp</applicationName>
        <applicationAssemblyName>myapp</applicationAssemblyName>

        <applicationVersion>0.4.61</applicationVersion>

        <!-- <applicationVersion>${application.version}</applicationVersion> -->

        <apiKey>s234W@#$WFW$@$@</apiKey>
        <getCallerData>false</getCallerData>
    </appender>

    ....

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="ADP-MESSAGING" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I tried by adding `${application.version}`, `${version}` but no success.

How can I do this? 
Please share your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The values interpolated in a `logback.xml` file are simply Java system properties. All you have to do is add a value to your Java commandline defining the value you want:

```scala
// NOTE: This will only work when running through sbt. You'll have to 
// append the same value to your startup scripts when running elsewhere.
javaOptions += "-Dapplication.version=" + version.value
```

With this flag, you should be able to interpolate the version in your XML file:

```xml
<applicationVersion>${application.version}</applicationVersion>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. we're running the application via a shell script. I'm looking for a way to dynamically update `<applicationVersion>` in `logback.xml` without modifying the shell script each time we run the application.

Comment: I think the other two options are pass through an argument to your shell script, or else edit `logback.xml` and commit it whenever `version.sbt` changes. Are either of these what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You can add logback PropertyDefiner implementation:

```scala
package org.mypackage

import ch.qos.logback.core.PropertyDefinerBase

class VersionPropertyDefiner extends PropertyDefinerBase {
  override def getPropertyValue: String = BuildInfo.version
}
```

You will get autogenerated (managed) scala code BuildInfo.version if you use [BuildInfoPlugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) in your project build settings.

Then you can define and use variable in your logback.xml configuration:

```xml
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">
    <define name="appVersion" class="org.mypackage.VersionPropertyDefiner"/>

    <appender name="ADP-MESSAGING" class="com.agoda.adp.messaging.logging.appenders.LogbackAppender">
        <applicationName>MyApp</applicationName>
        <applicationAssemblyName>myapp</applicationAssemblyName>

        <applicationVersion>${appVersion}</applicationVersion>

        <apiKey>s234W@#$WFW$@$@</apiKey>
        <getCallerData>false</getCallerData>
    </appender>

    ....

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="ADP-MESSAGING" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```